# Structure of a flutter project

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How to structure a flutter project like this one:
[Example restaurant pos image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijX9W.jpg)

Do you find this beginning of the tree structure correct:

```
class HomePageState extends State<HomePage>{
        @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          return MaterialApp(
              debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
              home: Scaffold(
                body: Row(
                  children: [
                    Container( // menu
                      width:60,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Expanded( // body
                      child: Container(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container( // ListProducts
                      width:300,
                      color: Colors.green,
                    ),

                  ],
                ),
                backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255 , 244 , 246, 250),
              )

          );
        }
    }
```

[code preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6z47L.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to place that `MaterialApp` into a separate parent widget (I think it will cause issues when using `MediaQuery` and `Theme` inside the same `build` method). It also might be cleaner down the line to extract every part (menu, body, ListProducts) into separate widgets.

Also, I would advise you to take a look at the [LayoutBuilder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IYDVcriKjsw) widget,
and the ressources on [this page](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/adaptive-responsive) if the app is meant to work on narrower screens.

Oh and if you don't know about state management, definitely [check this out](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/intro).

Comment: You're welcome ! If it was helpful, you can accept my answer as the right one.